# How to implement the swipe up and down number select Unity3d

Tags: unity

I want to implement the UI like in the image.

I want the users to select the number by swiping up and down.

I found the tutorial on the YouTube which is similar to the what i wanted (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL-FLsV3WRs)

But it shows only the numbers from 0 to 9. I want to show from 1 to N (n can be any number).

Any idea to help me to get this would be great.

[image: Swipe Up and Down Numbers]

Comment: Hi, the link you provided doesn't look at all like what image you posted... The video is about making a digital code lock? Unless its just me, that might confuse other people as to what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @D.Kallan I am saying similar, it is not same. :) 

In the video we can swipe from 0 to 9 however i want to swipe in a range of more greater numbers such as 500.

Comment: How have you tried modifying the tutorial's approach to work with larger numbers so far? Where in that process did you get stuck?